# jQuery Ajax Not Passing Values on MAMP Local mySQL Server

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, mamp

I am testing an application using a MAMP local Apache and mySQL server, however it seems that my code isn't passing the data properly through the jQuery ajax function, as I keep getting 'null' values in the success output. I'm not sure if there is usually a problem using the local server and jQuery ajax, or there is just something wrong with my code. Here it is for reference:

JS File:

```
var curX = 2;
var curY = 6;

function boundary(moveX, moveY) {
var world = document.getElementById('overworld');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/tilecheck.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {x: curX + moveX, y: curY + moveY},
    success: function(data) {
        curX += moveX;
        curY += moveY;

        var left = data.lefttile;
        var right = data.righttile;
        var top = data.toptile;
        var bot = data.bottomtile;
        var xypos = document.getElementById("coord");
        xypos.innerText = curX + ", " + curY;

        if(left == 1){
            $("#aleft").css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            $("#aleft").css('display', '');
        }
        if(right == 1){
            $("#aright").css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            $("#aright").css('display', '');
        }

        if(top == 1){
            $("#atop").css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            $("#atop").css('display', '');
        }
        if(bot == 1){
            $("#abottom").css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            $("#abottom").css('display', '');
        }
        world.style.marginTop = -curX * 351 +"px";
        world.style.marginLeft = -curY * 351 +"px";
    }
});
}
```

Which I call onload in the html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="game/bound.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="boundary(0,0);">
```

And here is the 'tilecheck.php' code that I call in the ajax function:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die ('Error Connecting');
    mysql_select_db('testing_db') or die ('No Database');

    $x = $_REQUEST['x'];
    $y = $_REQUEST['y'];

    $q = "SELECT bound FROM tiles WHERE xpos = ".($x - 1)." AND ypos = $y LIMIT 1";
    $lefttile = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($q));

    $q = "SELECT bound FROM tiles WHERE xpos = ".($x + 1)." AND ypos = $y LIMIT 1";
    $righttile = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($q));

    $q = "SELECT bound FROM tiles WHERE xpos = $x AND ypos = ".($y - 1)." LIMIT 1";
    $toptile = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($q));

    $q = "SELECT bound FROM tiles WHERE xpos = $x AND ypos = ".($y + 1)." LIMIT 1";
    $bottomtile = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($q));

    $json = array(
    "x" => $x,
    "y" => $y,
    "lefttile" => $lefttile, "righttile" => $righttile,
    "toptile" => $toptile, "bottomtile" => $bottomtile
);

$output = json_encode($json);
echo $output;

?>
```

What I want the code to do is grab a value from the database and hide or show arrow buttons depending on the value. Please let me know what you think and if you have any other questions. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I fiddled with the code a little, changing the ajax function to a post:

```
$.post('php/tilecheck.php', {x: curX + moveX, y: curY + moveY}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
```

And changed the $_REQUEST in the php to $_POST. The console when running this script shows this:

```
{"lefttile":"1","righttile":"1","toptile":"0","bottomtile":"1"}
```

When the variable passes "1" (the value of the bound row I called for in the mySQL) the corresponding arrow should disappear. However when I alert the variable I defined (var left = data.lefttile) and which the console shows is defined (in this instance, as 1) it reads 'undefined'. I'm not sure why. Thank you.

Comment: Think you'll want to swap $_REQUEST['x'] with $_POST['x']. You should use firebug to check what the PHP script is throwing as it's response

Comment: Why are you passing $y and $x as strings in your SQL?

Comment: @AdamWaite I tried using both $_POST and $_GET instead of $_REQUEST, but when I view the php file the variables are still passing the value 'null'. after I define $x and $y and try to echo their values, nothing is displayed on the screen. thank you for your answer.

Comment: Have you got error reporting switch on? Try sticking the following at the top of your PHP:

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: gives me this error: "Notice: Undefined index: x in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Development/ETL24/php/tilecheck.php on line 8" for both lines that define $x and $y